# Speeding up maven assembly of multiple modules

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm having a project of the following form

```
- pom.xml
- projectA
  - pom.xml
  - src/main/
    - java
    - startupScript
- projectB
  - pom.xml
  - src/main/
    - java
    - startupScript
- projectAssembly
  - pom.xml
```

I want `projectAssembly` to produce a tar.gz that would contain two folders one for projectA and one for projectB, in each folder, there would be project's dependencies and the `startupScript` library.

The "naive" way to do that is to add `assembly.xml` file to each project, a file which roughly looks like:

```
<assembly>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<baseDirectory>/${project.artifactId}</baseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/startupScripts</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/startupScripts</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
 </fileSets>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Then, in the `projectAssembly`, depend on `<type>tar.gz</type>` of both `projectA` and `projectB`, and add an assembly file which roughly looks like

```
<assembly>
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This works, however, I do not need the intermediate `tar.gz` of projects `A` and `B`, and producing them, especially if they have a lot of dependencies, takes a long time.

How can I tell maven to directly assembly only the tar.gz of `projectAssembly` without wasting times on packing and unpacking intermediate archives?

Comment: Do you need the dependencies in the project a and b tar.gz file? If not just remove the dependencySets from the assembly descriptor.

Comment: @khmarbaise but how would they appear in the final tar.gz created by `assemblyProject`?

Comment: Hi there! Which Maven version are you using?

Comment: @Jan Hi, 3.0.1. Doesn't seem to matter very much.

Comment: To me it does: I thought that moduleSets could help you but I would try that out before giving an answer - alas, I only use Maven 2.

Answer (score 1):

Your assembly descriptor in the projectAssembly needs to look something like this (See comments inside):

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>bin</id>
<formats>
  <format>dir</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<moduleSets>
  <moduleSet>

    <!-- Enable access to all projects in the current multimodule build! -->
    <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

    <!-- Now, select which projects to include in this module-set. -->
    <includes>
      <include>*:projectA</include>
      <include>*:projectB</include>
    </includes>

    <!-- Select and map resources from each module -->
    <sources>
      <includeModuleDirectory>false</includeModuleDirectory>
      <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>src/main/startupScript</directory>
          <outputDirectory>${module.artifactId}/startupScript</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
      </fileSets>
    </sources>

   <!-- Select and map dependencies from each module -->
    <binaries>
      <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
          <outputDirectory>${module.artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
      </dependencySets>
    </binaries>
  </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

I believe that would be what you need. If not let us know..